# Bloomed as an Adjective

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, adjectives

A **"thick-trunked tree"** means a tree with a thick trunk. Likewise, can we say **"fragrant-bloomed tree"** to say that the tree gives out fragrant blooms?

Comment: You can, but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: An adverb as the first component would be preferable: "a fragrantly-bloomed tree".

Comment: Poetry like verbs. flagrantly-bloomed tree is grammatically correct and poetically terrible. Much too heavy.

Comment: Who said anything about poetry? The OP makes no mention of poetry in their question, so don't assume it is.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any hard and fast rule against the usage you suggest, but I can't find any actual examples of the hyphenated form. Googling does throw up the occasional unhyphenated, "fragrant bloomed".

To test the basic structure, I did try "late" instead of "fragrant", and "late-bloomed" does appear in several places. However, what was obvious was that far more common is "late-**blooming**".

Conclusion: based on everyday usage, while "**fragrant-bloomed tree**" is probably acceptable, you might want to consider, "**fragrant-blooming tree**" as a safer alternative.

Comment: An adverb as the first component would be preferable: "a **fragrantly**-bloomed tree".

Comment: I'd also put "fragrant-blossomed" tree into the ring

Comment: They are different meanings. Fragrant-blooming means it sometimes produces fragrant blooms. Fragrant-bloomed means it has produced them now. (though, confusing because a metaphorical or generic tree may not have an obvious now)

Answer (score 2):

Generically yes, but this usage is rare at best for many possible combinations of adjective and noun.

The specific construct of taking a noun phrase with a single adjective and single noun, hyphenating it, and then adding ‘ed’ to the end to form an adjective is not linguistically productive (that is, it does not work for any arbitrary noun phrase that happens to fit the required structure), but it *is* recognized and understandable to most native speakers.

The complicating factor is that this type of adjective formation, even for the ‘common’ cases, is actually not all that common. There are a couple of idiomatic cases where the hyphenated form is preferred (such as ‘thick-headed’ or ‘hard-headed’ as synonyms for ‘stubborn’), but these are very much the exception and not the rule. For other cases, you can often come up with specific sentences that utilize the hyphenated form, but most possible usage can be rephrased to avoid it, and those forms are more common in cases where they are valid. For example, ‘a thick-trunked tree’ can be trivially rephrased as ‘a tree with a thick trunk’, and that second form is usually the preferred one. Similarly with ‘a fragrant-bloomed tree’ and ‘a tree with fragrant blooms’.

This particular case is also interesting though because ‘bloom’ is also a verb, and can be used to describe something trees do, so if the tree is blooming, you could also say ‘a fragrantly-blooming tree’ (the hyphen is optional here, I would not normally include it though).

Comment: "a fragrantly blooming tree" sounds good to me.

Comment: It is poetry. I am trying to minimize words and keep it concise.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bit weird, only because it's rare.

It's probably going to be easier for your readers to parse "blossomed" at a glance instead (because we use "blossom" in the context of trees a lot more than "bloom").

"Blossomed" also sounds like a more acceptable adjective than "bloomed". This could be for all sorts of reasons, perhaps only because it has a more established usage (Google Ngrams provides cursory evidence that [blossomed is more common than bloomed as an adjective](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bloomed_ADJ%2Cblossomed_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)), maybe because of some phonological reason (e.g. "blossomed" matches the trochaic stress pattern observed in most English adjectives, so it might naturally lend itself to being used as one), or a lexical one (conjecture: "bloom" is a state that the flower is in until it wilts, therefore a live flower can only be "blooming").

Feel free to use whichever one you want, there's no right answer - least of all in poetry. Use the one that captures the effect you want. At least to me: "bloomed" is about vitality, birth, flowers lens flares, and is in-your-face; "blossomed" is poignant, romantic, serene, multitudinous, dreamlike, promising, and timeless.